# How to instruct the gcc compiler to allocate a global variable in stack?

Tags: gcc, global-variables, local-variables

I am compiling a C code using gcc ARM cross-compiler. I wonder if there is a gcc option instructing the compiler to allocate a global variable in the stack rather than the data section. I checked [this link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html) but it does not mention anything useful to resolve my issue. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is it that you are really trying to accomplish? A global variable is global, which means that its lifetime exceeds the lifetime of the stack (which only exists within the lifetime of `main`).

Comment: I am experimenting with a multi-threaded application on a cycle-accurate simulator. I am using a barrier to synchronize the start of threads. The barrier is global so that it can be shared among threads. I don't want the barrier affects my timing model. I modified the timing model of the simulator so that only global variables are tracked, i.e., contribute to cycle time advancement. So, I need to have a global barrier (in the sense that it is shared among all threads) and it is mapped to stack so that it does not affect the timing model.

Comment: I suggest you put that useful information into the question, rather than leave it hiding in a comment. Probably, the threads will have to use a variable in the context of `main`. You could add a pointer to this variable to the thread argument. But perhaps someone will come up with a better solution for you.

Comment: I thought that the initial question is clear enough without distracting details.